# Communication between GPS Device with Android Tracking Application

Tags: android, gps, mobile-app-tracker

I have TK102 Gps Device and I wish to build simple Real-Time Tracking Application to track the device that will attach on a target vehicle. It is possible that I can communicate between the app with the GPS device without server-side to get the location provided by the GPS device and show it at the application?

The application will show the location provided by the GPS device continously with updated location since it is real time application.

I am a GIS student and have 5% of programming knowledge which is just C++ language not JAVA.

Comment: So the vehicle is in town A and your Android app in in...?

Comment: Let say my gps on vehicle send coordinate to server. The coordinate will be 100 lat , 100 long for example. How to retrieve the location data from server into my android app? My android app will get the data and mark on a map in the tracking layout. When the vehicle move, gps will track location data in 5sec as i set in the gps by sms command, and my android app when retrieve the update location data from the server and mark it on the map as a realtime tracking the vehicle. It will shoe the movement of the vehicle on the map. How to coding that in android studio on the .java?

Comment: You said you didnot want to use a server. And suddenly there is one. I dont understand you.

Comment: Owh I am very sorry. Its my bad. I am really confius since last week because of this problem. Thats other situation but regarding to my main question, we twist the situation I comment above with noserver side. It is possible that my android application can communicate with gps tracker device to retrieve the location data continously in real time? Gps will be on target vehicle, and android app will be use by others user to track the vehicle. Such as school bus tracker application